# Extraer nombre de variables usando regex en R

Tags: r, regex

¡Saludos!

Estoy intentando extraer el nombre de unas variables usando regex en R. Los datos se encuentran disponibles en https://apps.who.int/gho/portal/uhc-cabinet-wrapper-v2.jsp?id=1010501
He intentado usando la siguiente instrucción:

```
str_extract(names(data), '([:graph:])*(?=\\s(\\d{4}(-\\d{4})*))')
```

Pero el lookaround solamente devuelve la palabra más próxima a los años, por ejemplo:

```
> names(data)
 [1] "Country"                                                                    
 [2] "Data availability for UHC index of service coverage 2013-2017"              
 [3] "UHC index of service coverage (SCI) 2017"                                   
 [4] "UHC index of service coverage (SCI)_1 2015"                                 
 [5] "UHC SCI components: Reproductive, maternal, newborn and child health 2017"  
 [6] "UHC SCI components: Reproductive, maternal, newborn and child health_1 2015"
 [7] "UHC SCI components:  Infectious diseases 2017"                              
 [8] "UHC SCI components:  Infectious diseases_1 2015"                            
 [9] "UHC SCI components: Noncommunicable diseases 2017"                          
[10] "UHC SCI components: Noncommunicable diseases_1 2015"                        
[11] "UHC SCI components: Service capacity and access 2017"                       
[12] "UHC SCI components: Service capacity and access_1 2015"                     
> str_extract(names(data), '([:graph:])*(?=\\s(\\d{4}(-\\d{4})*))')
 [1] NA           "coverage"   "(SCI)"      "(SCI)_1"    "health"     "health_1"   "diseases"   "diseases_1"
 [9] "diseases"   "diseases_1" "access"     "access_1"
```

¿Alguna sugerencia que me pueda ayudar?

Gracias anticipadas

Comment: Bienvenido arlugones a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Y si en vez de extraer los nombres, no intentas buscar los años y eliminarlos?

```
nombres <- c("Country",                                                                    
             "Data availability for UHC index of service coverage 2013-2017",              
             "UHC index of service coverage (SCI) 2017",                                   
             "UHC index of service coverage (SCI)_1 2015",                                 
             "UHC SCI components: Reproductive, maternal, newborn and child health 2017",  
             "UHC SCI components: Reproductive, maternal, newborn and child health_1 2015",
             "UHC SCI components:  Infectious diseases 2017",                              
             "UHC SCI components:  Infectious diseases_1 2015",                            
             "UHC SCI components: Noncommunicable diseases 2017",                          
             "UHC SCI components: Noncommunicable diseases_1 2015",                        
             "UHC SCI components: Service capacity and access 2017",                       
             "UHC SCI components: Service capacity and access_1 2015")


gsub("( \\d{4}-\\d{4}$)| \\d{4}$", "",nombres)

 [1] "Country"                                                               
 [2] "Data availability for UHC index of service coverage"                   
 [3] "UHC index of service coverage (SCI)"                                   
 [4] "UHC index of service coverage (SCI)_1"                                 
 [5] "UHC SCI components: Reproductive, maternal, newborn and child health"  
 [6] "UHC SCI components: Reproductive, maternal, newborn and child health_1"
 [7] "UHC SCI components:  Infectious diseases"                              
 [8] "UHC SCI components:  Infectious diseases_1"                            
 [9] "UHC SCI components: Noncommunicable diseases"                          
[10] "UHC SCI components: Noncommunicable diseases_1"                        
[11] "UHC SCI components: Service capacity and access"                       
[12] "UHC SCI components: Service capacity and access_1"
```

También otra forma, sin patrones regulares, sería buscar el último espacio y eliminar lo que está a derecha:

```
unlist(lapply(strsplit(nombres, " "), function(x) {wc <- length(x);if (wc ==1){x} else {paste(x[1:(wc-1)], collapse=" ")}}))
```

Por último un comentario, he revisado los datos, y he probado importarlos con `read.csv()`, los nombres han quedado bien, solo hay una segunda fila dónde aparecen los años que eventualmente podría eliminarse.

Comment: ¡Excelente! No lo había pensado... Yo mismo he sido quien le agregué los años que aparecen en la segunda fila que comentas, sin embargo, lo que quisiera (ya que tengo los años agregados) es cambiar el formato de ancho a largo (usando pivot_longer con la opción names_pattern que permite desagregar usando los años). ¿Tal vez puedas ayudarme con esta variante?